# How do I plot this function graphically?

Tags: graphing-functions

Let $F(t)$ be a function of $t$, given by 
$$F(t) = t U(t)-(t-1) U(t-1) + (t-2) U(t-2) - (t-3) U(t-3)$$
where $U$ is the Heaviside step function.

I am getting confused regarding its graphical representation. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is $F(t)$ for $t<0$.

Comment: Draw each term on the RHS alone. For example draw $tU(t)$, $(t-1)U(t-1)$, and so on and add/subtract them graphically

Comment: I added the solution in my answer below. I think now it's better not to think about how each term looks like, it's better to think piecewise from $0$ to $1$, $1$ to $2$ and so on because $U(x)$ is zero for $x<0$.

Comment: Notice $tU(t) = \max(0,t)$. throwing the command `Plot[Max[t,0] - Max[t-1,0] + Max[t-2,0] - Max[t-3,0],{t,-2,5}]` to WA, you will get this [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[Max[t,0]-Max[t-1,0]%2BMax[t-2,0]-Max[t-3,0],{t,-2,5}]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The first term is

$$tU(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & t<0\\
t & t\geq 0
\end{cases}$$

the second

$$(t-1)U(t-1)=\begin{cases}
0 &t<1\\
t-1 & t\geq 1
\end{cases}$$

and so on... Can you take it from here?

**Edit:**

$$F(t)=
\begin{cases}
0, & t<0\\
t, & 0\leq t<1\\
1, & 1\leq t<2\\
t-1,& 2\leq t<3\\
2, &t\geq 3
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot. I am able to draw functions like U(t)+2U(t-1)+4U(t-2) - 3U(t-3), whose graph is a combination of step-like figures. But my professor said that the first term of the given function would give a straight line with 45 degree slope, which will continue till t=1 on the t axis, and so on. I, on the other hand, always thought that these functions yield some horizontal lines at different steps. Perhaps the graph could clarify everything.

Comment: Maybe you can do the next step when you subtract these two functions. What value holds for negative $t$, for $t\geq 1$ and for $0\leq t<1$?